# SQL query returning duplicate rows with join

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Similar question had been ask multiple times, but none of the answers help in this situation, so asking the question again

I have a table with this following structure(yeah no unique key here):

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
|a_number | a_status | b_status | ref_id | timepublished       |
|(text)   | (text)   | (text)   |(text)  | (datetime)          |
---------------------------------------------------------------
|1        | U        | U        | re1    | 2016-08-12 13:24:25 |
|1        | P        | U        | re1    | 2016-08-12 13:24:35 |
|1        | P        | P        | re1    | 2016-08-12 13:24:45 |
|2        | U        | U        | re2    | 2016-08-12 12:24:30 |
|2        | U        | F        | re1    | 2016-08-12 12:24:45 |
|4        | U        | U        | re3    | 2016-08-12 13:24:30 |
|4        | U        | U        | re4    | 2016-08-13 15:24:30 |
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now the problem I am trying to solve is to get the latest states for each a_number. So the CORRECT output should be:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
|1        | P        | P        | re1    | 2016-08-12 13:24:45 |
|2        | U        | F        | re1    | 2016-08-12 12:24:45 |
|4        | U        | U        | re3    | 2016-08-12 13:24:30 |
|4        | U        | U        | re4    | 2016-08-13 15:24:30 |
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

And the query I have is :

```
SELECT af.a_number
     , af.a_status
     , af.b_status
     , af.ref_id
     , af.timepublished
FROM af_biz af
 JOIN
 (SELECT MAX(timepublished) timepublished, ref_id
     FROM af_biz GROUP BY ref_id) tmp 
 ON tmp.timepublished = af.timepublished AND tmp.ref_id = af.ref_id
ORDER BY af.a_number;
```

But the result I get contain incorrect output like this (Notice that the time is max timepublished but statuses are different):

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
|1        | P        | U        | re1    | 2016-08-12 13:24:45 |
|1        | P        | P        | re1    | 2016-08-12 13:24:45 |
|2        | U        | U        | re2    | 2016-08-12 12:24:45 |
|2        | U        | F        | re1    | 2016-08-12 12:24:45 |
|4        | U        | U        | re3    | 2016-08-12 13:24:30 |
|4        | U        | U        | re4    | 2016-08-13 15:24:30 |
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

Anyone has any idea on what could be wrong with my query ??

Comment: You need to do `GROUP BY af.a_number`

Comment: @Sovon, which is invalid GROUP BY - not allowed in newer MySQL versions...

Comment: @Sovon, even though it's valid, shouldn't be done ... that works in MySQL cause of the extension provided by MySQL but will not work in any other RDBMS.

Comment: @Rahul, isn't every RDBMS has this syntax? I checked oracle, they also have it. Also, the question is related to MySql.

Comment: @Sovon, NO, the point is wrong `group by` ... you should include all columns present in select list to group by and not only a specific column. That's what the comments points put.

Comment: Ok, I forgot to mention, the table has multiple ref_id for each a_number. So in this case the output should have both ref_id for the account number. Edited the question to reflect this

Answer (score 1):

Please give this a try:

```
SELECT 
   af.a_number
 , af.a_status
 , af.b_status
 , af.ref_id
 , af.timepublished
FROM af_biz af
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
     a_number,
     MAX(timepublished) max_timepublished
    FROM af_biz 
    GROUP BY a_number
) AS t
ON af.a_number = t.a_number AND af.timepublished = t.max_timepublished
ORDER BY af.a_number
```

**First** you needed to group by `a_number`.  <sup>**(Since you want result for each `a_number`)**</sup>

**Second** later needed to join on matching `timepublished` and `a_number`  <sup>**(not `ref_id`)**</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Old fashioned but I have used sub query

Here it is :

```
select 
   testtable.a_number
  ,testtable.a_status
  ,testtable.b_status
  ,testtable.timepublished
 from testtable
  inner join
 (   select
       a_number
      ,max(timepublished) as date
     from
       testtable 
     group by
       a_number ) as anumberWithMaxDate
 on 
   testtable.a_number = anumberWithMaxDate.a_number and 
   testtable.timepublished = anumberWithMaxDate.date
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
SELECT af.a_number, af.a_status, af.b_status, af.ref_id, af.timepublished
FROM af_biz af
 JOIN
 (
SELECT MAX(timepublished) timepublished, 
afb.a_number+ afb.a_status+ afb.b_status+ afb.ref_id as key
     FROM af_biz afb 
GROUP BY afb.a_number+ afb.a_status+ afb.b_status+ afb.ref_id
) tmp 
 ON tmp.timepublished = af.timepublished 
AND tmp.key = (af.a_number+ af.a_status+ af.b_status+ af.ref_id)
ORDER BY af.a_number;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is expressing something different from what you want. And apparently you have some misunderstanding about joins. To explain your current query:

You generate a intermediate table of the form (refid,maxtimepublished), and for every refid you have exactly one entry. This is your right table in the join. The Join will match every left row (original table) with every right row, where the join condition is fulfilled.

Now, the max time for `refid=1` is `2016-08-12 12:24:45`, so every row of the left table (original) with `refid=1` and `timepublished='2016-08-12 12:24:45'` will end up in the result. Which is the third and the fifth row.
Repeat for `refid=2` and the fourth row will be output as well. With `refid=3` the last row will be ouput.

Those are 4 rows, which doesn't match the output you claim you got. But that's probably just an error.

I think you have to make some assumptions about your data. For example:

> for every `a_number` there will be at most one entry for any given time (independent of `ref_id`)

In that case you could replace every `ref_id` in your query with `a_number` and be done with it. (which is also 1000111's and Abhijit Chowdhury's answer)

Comment: I cannot make assumption that there would be atmost one entry (making that assumption makes it a unique key which make the problem lot more easier). I have edited my question to reflect that

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    A_NUMBER,A_STATUS,B_STATUS,REF_ID,TIMEPUBLISHED
from  
    TABL
where 
    TIMEPUBLISHED in (select 
                          b.TIMEPUBLISHED
                      from 
                          (select 
                               A_NUMBER,max(TIMEPUBLISHED) as TIMEPUBLISHED
                           from TABL
                               group by A_NUMBER) b )
;
```